# How to highlght custom days in ng-bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I cant use custom template to do that because Angular checks [class.someClass]="some()" on every mouse move, and that takes a loot of resource. Is there any way to give dates once to datepicker and it could refernce to them and set necesery classes to them? (something similar like pipes work)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45525351/6251232

Comment: That is a working solution, that I am using right know, but that is not a good solution, because Angular is calling that function with loop on every mouse move.